# What progression is most commonly used together with the '50s progression?

Tags: composition, chord-progressions

I have **I-vi-IV-V** repeated three times (I think it's called the [50s progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50s_progression)) plus turnaround **I-vi-ii-I**, and want a similar progression repeating afterwards but that subjectively feels at a higher pitch.

I tried **V-iii-vi-ii** and **V-iii-I-ii**, with turnaround **V-IV-iii-ii**, but I'd like to know what would be the most commonly used progression for this propose.

The chords I'm currently using are:

**C-Am/E-F-G** repeats three times plus turnaround **C-Am/E-Dm-C**.

Then **G-Em-Am7-Dsus2** or **G-Em-C6-Dsus2** three times with turnaround **G-F-Em-Dm**.

Comment: I've always called it 1-6-4-5, which sounds as you say. But apart from the common 12 bar pattern and the Spanish sequence, nothing else pops into view. Hence comment, not answer.

Comment: @Tim I updated the question with the turnarounds, I will try both suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do the same sort of thing, but higher, why not do the same sort of thing but higher?  This is very much in the style of vintage pop.

[image]

Comment: I've transposed it to C major and came up with Eb-Cm-Ab6-Bb7 with some inversions that make it closer to the G-Em-C6-Dsus2 that I had for the second part, although I would keep the later, which is more similar to the C-Am/E-F-G in the first part. I'm accepting your answer though, that has the score of that song, which was very popular in the '50s and is pretty close to what I was looking for. [This](https://soundcloud.com/rraallvv/theme-5) is the result by the way, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's another popular sequence that has been used from the 1700s until the present: I7-IV-ii65-V7 (with various other inversions possible.) One can get a nice progression of AABA' using I-vi-ii-V, I-vi-ii-V, I7-iv6-ii6-V7, I-ii-V7-I; the vi chords can be replaced with IV chords and the I7 with I and the iv6 with an iv or IV or IV6 or IV7 or similar.

Answer (score 1):

'Why Do Fools Fall in Love?', recorded by Frankie Lymon and the Teenagers, features a simple I IV I I7 turnaround leading to the bridge.

Comment: Nice song from the '50s, it has a cover by Diana Ross. I'll take a look to the chords to see if there is something like what I'm looking for, thanks.